# Создание формы, которая позволяет выбрать цвет

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Подскажите, как подобную функциональность можно реализовать на WPF?

Comment: В WpfToolkit есть ColorCanvas и ColorPicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте свой `UserControl` с картинкой типа этой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и по координатам мышки берите цвет. Можете [тут](https://github.com/Jagailo/YetAnotherKeyDisplayer/blob/master/YAKD/Controls/ColorPicker/ColorPicker.xaml.cs) глянуть подробнее